# How To Submit Angular Form with a Nested Component

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7, angular-forms

I have a dateTime component that I built that I am going to use throughout an application. I have a formGroup that I am using to submit a form on a separate component, and I need this component to be a part of that form. I can't seem to get the data from the child form to show in the parentForm. Is there a way to set this as a property/ value of the parent form?

**Child DateTime Picker HTML:**

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput [ngxMatDatetimePicker]="picker" placeholder="{{ name }}" [formControl]="dateControl" required="true">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <ngx-mat-datetime-picker #picker startView="year"></ngx-mat-datetime-picker>
</mat-form-field>
```

**Child Typescript:**

```
@Input() name: string;
@Input() displayTime: boolean;
@Input() allowDateInPast: boolean;

public dateControl = new FormControl();

constructor() { }

ngOnInit() {

}
```

**Parent HTML/form:**

```
<form [formGroup]="formGroup">
<mat-label>Name</mat-label>
    <input type="textfield" formControlName="reportName" matInput required="true" placeholder="Report Name" name="reportName">
</mat-form-field>

<div class="col-sm">
    <app-datetime-picker [name]="'Start Date'" [displayTime]="true" [allowDateInPast]="true"></app-datetime-picker>
</div>

<button class="float-right" [disabled]="formGroup.invalid" (click)="createReport()" mat-raised-button color="primary">Save</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

**Parent Typescript:**

```
formGroup: FormGroup = new FormGroup({

reportName: new FormControl("", Validators.required),
// ?? something here
});
```

Is this possible? Would I need to use @Output() in some manner?

Thanks for any help.
Travis W-

Comment: You should implement the `ControlValueAccessor` interface in your date picker. Check this Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-oe2eth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I usually do is I pass the FormControl down as an input. So on the child component you have an input:
`@Input() dateControl: FormControl;`

In your parent html you pass down the FormControl like:
`<app-datetime-picker [dateControl]="formGroup['dateControl'] >`

You can now read the properties of the FormControl in the parent component just as normal.

I do agree with the other answers as well, control value accessor would be a good solution for this, but a bit harder to implement.

Comment: I built a new answer based off this one. A mixture of your answer and some googling around is what finally helped me solve it.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Since you want you `app-datetime-picker` component to be used as a form control, I'd make sure you implement [ControlValueAccessor](https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor). This will allow you to use it as if it was something like an `<input>` or `<select>`.

Your date picker control will look something like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-datetime-picker',
  templateUrl: './app-datetime-picker.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app-datetime-picker.css'],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => DateControlPicker),
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})
export class DateTimePicker implements ControlValueAccessor {
  disabled = false;
  innerValue: Date;

  //Make sure your template calls this function to update the value
  valueChanged(obj: Date) {
    this.writeValue(obj); //save the value so this component can render it
    this.onChangeCallback(obj); //update the form
  }

  //satisfy the ControlValueAccessor interface
  //the forms library will call this when the form is first initialized or when the control is updated by the code "myFormGroup.controls['someControlName'].patchValue(new Date())"
  writeValue(obj: any): void {
    this.selectedValue = obj;
  }

  //Register a callback - this callback function is what we neeed to call to update that form
  registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    this.onChangeCallback = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
    this.onTouchedCallback = fn;
  }

  setDisabledState(isDisabled: boolean): void {
    this.disabled = isDisabled;
  }

  private onTouchedCallback: () => void = () => {
  };
  private onChangeCallback: (_: any) => void = () => {
  };
}
```

Then you can use it in template that has a form:

```
<form [formGroup]="myFormGroup">
    <app-datetime-picker formControlName="myControlName"></app-datetime-picker>
</form>
```

The code-behind to build the form group:

```
constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder){}

ngOnInit(){
    this.myFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
        myDateControlName: new FormControl(new Date());
    })
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Inspired by @SnorreDan ... but here is a more complete answer.

Here is the child component TS:

```
@Input() dateTime: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
    startDate: new FormControl("", Validators.required),
  });


constructor() { 
    this.dateTime = new FormGroup({});
    this.dateTime.addControl("startDate", new FormControl());
  }
```

In the child html:

```
<mat-form-field>
      <input matInput [ngxMatDatetimePicker]="picker" placeholder="{{ placeholder }}" required="true" formControlName="startDate">
      <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
      <ngx-mat-datetime-picker #picker startView="year"></ngx-mat-datetime-picker>
</mat-form-field>
```

In the parent formGroup:

```
 // This is important! It must match what is in the child component.
 formGroup: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
    startDate: new FormControl("", Validators.required),
 });
```

finally the parent HTML:

```
<app-datetime-picker [dateTime]="formGroup" [placeholder]="'Start Date'" [endDate]="false" [displayTime]="false" [allowDateInPast]="true"></app-datetime-picker>
```

Happy to answer any questions for anyone who struggles through this one! Took me way longer than it should have.

Comment: You should check @spots' answer. It's much better than this one.

Comment: Can you help me understand why it's better? Seems like the simpler answer is this one. What makes it worse?